# Unattended questions by the OP

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, accepted-answer, abandoned-questions

There are lots of questions in Stack Overflow, more depending on the specific tag, where obviously, the more the language or framework is used, the more questions there are. I got to think that there are a lot of newcomer questions where there is no feedback once they are answered or commented on when the community tries to provide some help.
This leads the helpers to find the major questions of a specific tag cluttered with most of the time beginner questions that many of the times are unattended, because maybe the OP found a solution, or maybe because he or she does not care anymore.
In my case when I ask, I follow the question I post because I am struggling to find an answer and I am eager to discover what the solution can be, and in case some help is provided I react quickly to the comment or answer so as to be thankful and to provide feedback to the kind helper that took some of his time to help me.

There are mechanisms in Stack Overflow to manage the clutter of questions and debug the whole, so that there is a kind of neat knowledge source and the info can be found properly.

Poured into the void and left unattended questions, lead to a kind of spam perception when a tag with a lot of activity is followed, do not contribute to the Stack Overflow's wisdom database improvement or maintenance and does not reward the helpers will to help (not meaning Stack Overflow's reputation reward, but just on the human side, the reward of receiving feedback to something/someone the helper has dedicated a bit of time to).

Shouldn't there be some kind of penalization mechanism for asked questions that then are left unattended?

Comment: What do you mean by "unattended"? Why do we care if the asker never comes back? All a Q&A site needs to thrive are the questions and the answers, not the original posters.

Comment: "not meaning SO's reputation reward, but just on the human side, the reward of receiving feedback to something/someone the helper has dedicated a bit of time to" The feedback an OP could (or should) give on SO is up- or downvoting an answer or accepting it and is therefore linked to reputation. So when you don't mean reputation, what is it? Also, SO tries to be a knowledge base, not a personal help desk so the OP actually doesn't matter that much or at all. And what kind of penalty, eg. for a user that didn't log in for years, for example?

Comment: what is it? -> To know if the OP has even read the answer or comment maybe, not known by the helper, meaning to be known by SO to prevent the kind of question "spamming"

Comment: Why does that even matter?

Comment: maybe that could lead to a healthier question db, because it demands a little bit of effort on the OPs side...

Comment: It is certainly a problem that the ***top*** search engine results nowadays tend to be low-scored duplicates with little activity (often with a useless answer) and ***no*** indication of where the canonical question is, but it would be better if Stack Overflow gave less [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) juice to those low-scored questions. Stack Overflow is a very inefficient research tool (it takes way too long to find the canonical questions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- If you think the question is a duplicate, vote/flag to close it as such, off-topic vote/flag to close.
- If you think it's useful upvote, not useful downvote.

Makes no difference who asked it or whether they are present or not. Are you voting? That's the solution here. The power is in your hands.